# Trigger a method when calling another method in java (or how to do aop without aop)

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I'm trying to achieve the functionality of "before" and "after" method invocation.

1. I tried spring-aop, but it was buggy (I suspect that it's the combination of groovy in my java application).
2. I don't want to use java reflection.
3. I think that creating a method with function as parameter is not suitable here because the functions already exists in another class.

Here's what I'm trying to do (this is only part of the activities, I have 10 more like this):

```
            long startTimeMetric = System.nanoTime()
            Timer timer = meterRegistry.timer("item 1")
            myObject.theActivity(mediaContainer)
            timer.record(System.nanoTime() - startTimeMetric, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)

            long startTimeMetric = System.nanoTime()
            Timer timer = meterRegistry.timer("item 2")
            myObject2.theActivity2(mediaContainer)
            timer.record(System.nanoTime() - startTimeMetric, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
```

How can I make the repetitive first second and fourth line in each bucket automatic and elegant?

Thanks ahead.

edit: 
The problem I mentioned with aop is that I'm getting all of the sudden null pointers, whereas without the aop, it was OK.
How did I implement the aop?

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyMonitor{}

@Aspect
@Component
public class TimeMonitoringAspect {

    @Autowired
    MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    @Around("@annotation(com.path.to.MyMonitor)")
    public void before(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        long startTimeMetric = System.nanoTime();
        String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        Timer timer = meterRegistry.timer(methodName);
        joinPoint.proceed();
        timer.record(System.nanoTime() - startTimeMetric, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    }

}
```

For each method that I wanted to measure time, I annotated @MyMonitor before the method, and it worked most of the time, but in some cases, it gave the null pointer as I mentioned.

Comment: There is nothing buggy about spring AOP. It's mature  a proven technology!

Comment: You do not present any proof for your claim that Spring AOP is "buggy". While of course it is perfectly possible that you hit a bug, forgive me for assuming that the problem sits in front of the computer. I have been doing AOP support here for a couple of years and usually people don't read the manual, don't learn about Spring AOP's limitations in comparison to AspectJ and never put any effort in understanding the general concept of AOP or AspectJ syntax. So why don't you present your AOP problem here by actual code so we can decide whether to file a bug report or just fix your own bug?

Answer (score 2):

As far as AOP is concerned, you can still achieve using the following approaches.

1. Using Decorator Pattern. Refer this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and this [link](https://crosscuttingconcerns.com/AOP-vs-decorator)
2. You can use Java's InvocationHandler, refer this [link](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/03/create-your-own-aop-in-java.html). However it uses Proxy.
3. You can also use CGLib, refer this [link](http://cliffmeyers.com/blog/2006/12/29/spring-aop-cglib-or-jdk-dynamic-proxies.html). It uses reflection.

Spring provides a easy way to AOP which is used in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use lambda expressions:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        executeActivity(meterRegistry, "item 1", Task::theActivity, mediaContainer);
        executeActivity(meterRegistry, "item 2", Task::theActivity2, mediaContainer);
    }

    public static void executeActivity(MeterRegistry meterRegistry, String name, Consumer<Object> theActivity, Object mediaContainer) {
        long startTimeMetric = System.nanoTime();
        Timer timer = meterRegistry.timer(name);
        theActivity.accept(mediaContainer);
        timer.record(System.nanoTime() - startTimeMetric, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

    }
    public interface MeterRegistry {

        Timer timer(String name);

        void record(Long time);
    }
```

Comment: Your `MeterRegistry` interface has `record` method from `Timer` interface.